# Writing create_tree_digraph plot to a png file in Python

Tags: python, plot, lightgbm

I want the tree of my lightgbm model to save to a .png format. I have tried two plotting methods from lightgbm API - plot_tree and create_tree_diagraph.

```
import lightgbm as lgb
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris

X, y = load_iris(True)
clf = lgb.LGBMClassifier()
clf.fit(X, y)
```

When I use plot_tree, it displays the tree but in place of values there are small blank boxes

```
lgb.plot_tree(clf, tree_index=0)
```

When I try the create_tree_diagraph, I get the graph but I cant save it as it is.

```
lgb.create_tree_digraph(clf)
```

I used the below code to save it a file but that gets saved as the first plot (using plot_tree)

```
import graphviz
s = graphviz.Source(graph_b.source, filename = "test1.gv", format = "png")
s.view()
```

Any suggestions to save the plot as an image. I ultimately want to write these tree plots to excel.
I am using graphviz version 0.8.3
Thanks,

Answer (score 4):

I suppose you are using a jupyter notebook or something like that.
This worked for me, but surely is not the best way.

```
ax = lgb.create_tree_digraph(clf)
with open('fst.svg', 'w') as f:
    f.write(ax._repr_svg_())
```

Comment: Thanks. Not sure why but on this particular machine I could only save in svg format.

Comment: I do not know, why, but in svg format is easier to transform it to .png or .jpg